# curl extending the page load time in php

Tags: php, curl

> I am using google distance matrix api to get distance between two
>   points ,but my curl doesn't seems to work ,I am using linux shared
>   hosting with curl enabled in it ,all other websites hosted there are having no
>   issue regarding this ,but this particular page is either not loading
>   or if loads does,nt shows the distance calculated.I tried removing
>   this particular code and page opened in jiffy !! Any idea why?

```
<?php
$origin = urlencode($_SESSION['source']);
$destination = urlencode($_SESSION['destination']);

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$origin&destinations=$destination&key=Apikey";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response_a = json_decode($response, true);
$distance=$response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
?>
```

Comment: I tried checking the php error log ,it showws "file doesnot exist" ,whenever I tried accessing this particular file

Comment: echo $url, put the string in a browser -- what do you get?

Comment: the page is not loading giving 504 error ,and the url is working fine if accessed by address bar